# Specifying wildcard paths for PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a directory structure that is 2 folders deep(e.g. `folder1/folder1/file1.txt`, `folder1/folder2/file1.txt`, etc.). I need to traverse the directory structure recursively to extract all the data of the text files and put them in one large text file in the folder above. The command is:

```
Get-Content .\*\*\*.txt | Out-File ..\whole.txt
```

Here's the error for this command:

```
Get-Content : An object at the specified path .\*\*\*.geojson does not exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or
-Exclude parameter.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Content .\*\*\*.geojson | Out-File ..\whole_us.geojson
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.String[]:String[]) [Get-Content], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

How do I specify wildcard paths?

Comment: Try `Get-Content -Path .\*\*\*.txt`

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Comment: At least in the registry, I've found wild card paths to be inefficient. If you're curious, try the following (assumes there aren't .txt files in the first two levels) : `gci *.txt -recurse -Depth 2 |  Get-Content | Out-File ..\whole.txt`

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Please post as answer and add some explanation to it so the OP can accept it.

Comment: The error message is **not** the result of the code line you show. The message mentions you used extension `.geojson` (and no file with that extension exist), where in your code snippet you want to get the content of `.txt` files.

Answer (score 2):

> have a directory structure that is 2 folders deep(e.g. folder1/folder1/file1.txt, folder1/folder2/file1.txt, etc.). I need to traverse the directory structure recursively to extract all the data of the text files and put them in one large text file in the folder above. The command is:
>
> Get-Content .***.txt | Out-File ..\whole.txt
>
> Here's the error for this command:
>
> Get-Content : An object at the specified path .***.geojson does not
> exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or
> -Exclude parameter. At line:1 char:1
>
> How do I specify wildcard paths?

As explained in a [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1682848/specifying-wildcard-paths-for-powershell#comment2584245_1682848) to your question, it appears that the file extension of the input file does not match the file extension of the file that actually exists.  This means that your syntax isn't correct. The description for the -PATH parameter is as follows:

> Specifies the path to an item where Get-Content gets the content. Wildcard characters are permitted. The paths must be paths to items, not to containers. For example, you must specify a path to one or more files, not a path to a directory.

You will want to run the following command instead.

```
Get-Content -PATH .\*\*\*.txt | Out-File ..\whole.txt
```

The parameters for [Get-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1) are documented as follows:

```
Get-Content
   [-ReadCount <Int64>]
   [-TotalCount <Int64>]
   [-Tail <Int32>]
   [-Path] <String[]>
   [-Filter <String>]
   [-Include <String[]>]
   [-Exclude <String[]>]
   [-Force]
   [-Credential <PSCredential>]
   [-Delimiter <String>]
   [-Wait]
   [-Raw]
   [-Encoding <Encoding>]
   [-AsByteStream]
   [-Stream <String>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Source: [Get-Content Syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1#syntax)